# Operadores lógicos javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma dúvida

Porque essa operação não funciona?

```
if ($(v).attr('jgForm-required') || $(v).attr('jgForm-email') && $(v).is(":visible")) {
......................
}
```

E essa funciona ? Qual a diferença?

```
if ($(v).attr('jgForm-required') || $(v).attr('jgForm-email')) {
    if($(v).is(":visible")){
    ...............................
    }
}
```

[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/yqfgkxuj/)

Comment: Pode criar uma demo(jsFiddle) desse caso ?

Comment: Sem saber o que é `v` e os atributos, fica um pouco complicado de explicar... Poderia mostrar pra gente o que é a variável v?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O operador *and* (`&&`) tem maior [precedência](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) do que o *or* (`||`). Isso quer dizer que, numa sequência de *ands* e *ors*, os *ands* são resolvidos antes. Portanto a primeira versão é interpretada como:

```
X || (Y && Z)
```

Você pode forçar a interpretação que quer usando parênteses:

```
(X || Y) && Z
```

Ou seja:

```
if ( ($(v).attr('jgForm-required') || $(v).attr('jgForm-email')) && $(v).is(":visible")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: É isso mesmo! muito obrigado pela explicação!